# number of real roots of the equation?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, roots

number of real roots of the equation

$11^x+13^x+17^x-19^x=0$.

I don't remember similar questions done. Since this is not a polynomial equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**

Rewrite it as $$\left(\frac{11}{19}\right)^x+
\left(\frac{13}{19}\right)^x+
\left(\frac{17}{19}\right)^x=1$$

What can you say abou the function on the left-hand side?

Comment: How do we get the solution $x\approx 3.87479$?

Comment: @LukeCollins You have to do it numerically.  Even bisection will work fast enough for this one, I would guess.

Comment: I misread, and thought the asker was after solutions, not number of solutions.

Comment: @LukeCollins Oh I see.  No problem.